# Реализация search-bar по макету

Tags: html, css, анимация

Есть задача. По макету нужно реализовать строку поиска с помощью css (пока что без js)

[image: строка поиска]

Сделано, пока что, так ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/Sfairath/pen/BaJzPbX)). Вопрос:
Состояние `focus` сделано с помощью `:focus-visible`, и когда я в этом состоянии кликаю на кнопку или жму пробел, ничего не происходит. Можно ли как-то сделать это через `:active` и заставить строку не сворачиваться при отпускании пробела/лкм?
Вопрос номер два: как избавиться от этого эффекта (это кусок кнопки "закрыть"? Появляется через раз, на некоторых устройствах такой проблемы нет.

[image: кусок кнопки "закрыть"]

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9b06a412d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="search navlist__item">
  <button class="search-btn search-btn__find">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Что будем искать?" class="search__text" tabindex="-1">
  <button class="search-btn search-btn__close" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

```css
body{
  background: #4b0082;
}
.search{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content :center;
}
.search-btn{
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.search-btn__find{
  order: 2;
}
.search-btn__close{
  order: 3;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search__text{
  order: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #cacaca;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search__text::placeholder{
  color: #cacaca;
}

.search-btn__find:focus:not(:focus-visible) ~ .search__text,
.search__text:focus{
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cacaca;
}

.search-btn__find:focus:not(:focus-visible),
.search-btn__find:hover:not(:focus-visible){
  color: #ff9900;
  outline: none;
}
.search-btn__find:focus:not(:focus-visible) ~ .search-btn__close,
.search__text:focus ~ .search-btn__close{
  width: 32px;
}
.search-btn__find:focus-visible{
  outline: 2px solid #ff9900;
}

.search-btn__close:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось нечто похожее

```css
.search-btn__find:focus:not(:focus-visible) ~ .search__text,
.search-btn__find:focus-visible:active ~ .search__text,
.search__text:focus{
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cacaca;
}

.search-btn__find:focus:not(:focus-visible),
.search-btn__find:hover:not(:focus-visible),
.search-btn__find:active:focus-visible{
  color: #ff9900;
  outline: none;
}
```

Остался 1 вопрос, как оставить цвет `.search-btn__find{color: #ff9900}` при фокусе на `.search__text`?